# About the ambiguous description of sigwait()

Tags: c, linux, signals

> If no signal in
>          set is pending at the time of the call, the thread shall be
>   suspended until one or more becomes
>   pending. The signals defined by set
>   shall have been blocked  at  the
>          time of the call to sigwait(); otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>   The effect of sigwait() on the signal
>   actions for the signals in set is
>   unspecified.

This is really ambiguous ,what's the difference between `pending` and `block` here?

And its conclusion on how to choose between `sigwait` and `sigaction` is not clear at all:

> In summary, when it is necessary for
>   code run in response to an
>   asynchronous signal to notify a
>   thread, sigwait() should be used  to 
>   handle  the  signal.  Alterna-
>          tively,  if the implementation provides semaphores, they also can be
>   used, either following sigwait() or
>   from within a signal handling routine
>   previously registered
>          with sigaction().

Can someone make the reason of `sigwait` more rational?

Comment: It suspends execution of the thread until a specified signal is received. How is that not rational?

Comment: 1.what's the difference between pending and block here?2.how to choose between sigwait and sigaction,more clearly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Every process has what's called a *signal mask* associated with it, which defines the set of signals which are *blocked*.  The signal mask can be queried or set with [`setprocmask(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) (for single-threaded code) and [`pthread_sigmask(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_sigmask) (for multithreaded code).

Whenever a signal is raised (either explicitly via [`kill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) or [`raise(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/raise), or via some other mechanism such as a segmentation fault raising `SIGSEGV`), the signal is checked against the current signal mask.  If the signal is not blocked, then it is acted upon immediately: the corresponding signal handler is called if set, otherwise the default action (typically exiting with abnormal status or ignoring it) is run.  If the signal is blocked by the signal mask, then the state of the signal is set to *pending*, and the program continues execution.

So consider the following example program:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void on_sigusr1(int sig)
{
  // Note: Normally, it's not safe to call almost all library functions in a
  // signal handler, since the signal may have been received in a middle of a
  // call to that function.
  printf("SIGUSR1 received!\n");
}

int main(void)
{
  // Set a signal handler for SIGUSR1
  signal(SIGUSR1, &on_sigusr1);

  // At program startup, SIGUSR1 is neither blocked nor pending, so raising it
  // will call the signal handler
  raise(SIGUSR1);

  // Now let's block SIGUSR1
  sigset_t sigset;
  sigemptyset(&sigset);
  sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1);
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);

  // SIGUSR1 is now blocked, raising it will not call the signal handler
  printf("About to raise SIGUSR1\n");
  raise(SIGUSR1);
  printf("After raising SIGUSR1\n");

  // SIGUSR1 is now blocked and pending -- this call to sigwait will return
  // immediately
  int sig;
  int result = sigwait(&sigset, &sig);
  if(result == 0)
    printf("sigwait got signal: %d\n", sig);

  // SIGUSR1 is now no longer pending (but still blocked).  Raise it again and
  // unblock it
  raise(SIGUSR1);
  printf("About to unblock SIGUSR1\n");
  sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
  printf("Unblocked SIGUSR1\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
SIGUSR1 received!
About to raise SIGUSR1
After raising SIGUSR1
sigwait got signal: 30
About to unblock SIGUSR1
SIGUSR1 received!
Unblocked SIGUSR1
```

Comment: Actually every thread has a signal mask, not just every process, and `pthread_sigmask` is safe to use in any thread, but `sigprocmask` might misbehave if used in multithreaded programs.

Comment: @R.. ,I found another API `sigsuspend` which seems to have the same function as `sigwait`....

Comment: It seems that the big difference between the two is that `sigaction` provides a means by which signals are handled externally to any thread in the process (the signal catching function is not part of any thread's normal flow of execution). But `sigwait` provides a way for signals to be handled directly within one (or more) of the process's threads (the handling is done as part of the thread's normal flow of execution). This would mean that using `sigwait` puts fewer restrictions on the handling code. Using `sigaction` means the handling code is restricted to "signal safe" actions. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

From the `signal(7)` man page:

> ```
> Signal Mask and Pending Signals
>     A  signal  may  be  blocked,  which means that it will not be delivered
>     until it is later unblocked.  Between the time when it is generated and
>     when it is delivered a signal is said to be pending.
> ```

"Pending" and "blocked" are not mutually exclusive.

Also from the `signal(7)` man page:

> ```
> Synchronously Accepting a Signal
>     Rather than asynchronously catching a signal via a signal  handler,  it
>     is  possible to synchronously accept the signal, that is, to block exe-
>     cution until the signal is delivered, at which point the kernel returns
>     information about the signal to the caller.  There are two general ways
>     to do this:
>
>     * sigwaitinfo(2), sigtimedwait(2),  and  sigwait(3)  suspend  execution
>       until  one  of  the signals in a specified set is delivered.  Each of
>       these calls returns information about the delivered signal.
> ```

So `sigaction()` is used to allow other code to run until a signal is pending, whereas `sigwait()` suspends execution of the thread until a signal is pending but blocked.

Comment: `The signals defined by set shall have been blocked at the time of the call to sigwait();` how do we ensure that ,do we need to run additional code to ensure that,or automatically done inside sigwait?

Comment: *Also* from the `signal(7)` man page: "Each  thread  in  a process has an independent signal mask, which indicates the set of signals that the  thread  is  currently  blocking.   A thread  can  manipulate its signal mask using pthread_sigmask(3).  In a traditional single-threaded application, sigprocmask(2) can be used  to manipulate the signal mask."

Comment: @cpuer: Yes, you must have blocked them with `sigprocmask` or equivalent. "Shall" is used to indicate requirements the standard places on the application programmer.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams ,will it cause memory to be wasted if too many signals are blocked there?

Comment: The mask exists whether or not the signals are blocked. If you're asking about pending signals being blocked then I couldn't tell you; I don't know the kernel's internal structures that well.

Comment: I'm not asking the exact structure of pending signals,just doubting whether memory will be eaten up quickly if signals continues being blocked there...

Comment: Signals aren't supposed to be triggered that often; if they are, then you're deliberately doing something with them anyway and they won't build up.

Comment: How is it guaranteed that they won't build up? Is there any reference?

Comment: Other than the code that has been written to deal with them? Not that I know of.

Comment: So you're sure the kernel code will guarantee the signals won't build up?

Comment: Nope. But if you're deliberately doing something with the signals then you probably have a plan to deal with them. I mean, unless your program is insane.

Comment: @cpuer - Standard signals do not accumulate.  Only one (per signal type) can be pending at any time.  Any others of that type that are generated while one is pending are thrown away.  It is different for realtime signals.  They will be queued up to some system limit.  Unfortunately in linux this limit and where to find it depends on what kernel version you are using.  In any case, there *is* an upper limit imposed so the system is not going to signal itself out of memory resources and crash.

Comment: @Duck ,what's the difference between standard signals and realtime signals?Aren't they just numbers under the hood?

Comment: The **Real-time Signals** section of the `signal(7)` man page talks about them.

Comment: Ok,so 32-63 is for rt signals.Are there any other categories of signals besides starndard and realtime signals?

Comment: @cpuer - RT signals are SIGRTMIN + N up to SIGRTMAX.  I forget but I think on linux SIGRTMIN is 34 or 36 because threads silently use a couple for internal reasons.  It's just those two types and you won't run into RT under normal circumstances but if you do, they are queued.