# Why is signalhandler not outputting anything?

Tags: c++, linux, signals

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void sighandler(int sig) {
    cout << "signal received" << endl;
}

int main() {

    int pid= getpid();
    cout << pid << endl;

    signal( SIGUSR1, sighandler );

    sigset_t accept;
    sigaddset( &accept, SIGUSR1 );
    int s;

    sigwait(&accept, &s);

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program and send a SIGUSR1 signal to it via "kill -s SIGUSR1 $pid" it just outputs the number of the signal (10) but not the text in sighandler. I don't understand why. This is on a Linux System.

Comment: You might want to add `sigemptyset(&accept)` prior to your `sigaddset`.

Comment: using `cout` in a signal handler invokes [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013202/i-need-a-list-of-async-signal-safe-functions-from-glibc). Don't do that, write a signal handler [correctly](http://lazarenko.me/2013/01/15/how-not-to-write-a-signal-handler/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`sigwait - wait for queued signals`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigwait.html)

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The sigwait() function selects a pending signal from set, atomically **clears it from the system's set of pending signals**, and returns that signal number in the location referenced by sig.

So, by using `sigwait()`, the signal is already delivered and dealt with by your program.

When you remove the `sigwait` call and do a sleep or busy waiting, the `SIGUSR1` signal will be delivered to your signal handler and the message "signal received" will be printed.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this behavior because when you call `sigwait()` your thread gets put to sleep and control gets passed to the OS. When you send the `SIGUSR1` signal, it is getting handled by the OS, and then the OS wakes up your thread and passes control back. Even though you've registered a signal handler, your handler is not getting called because the signal has been handled by the time your thread is re-awakened.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to find a definitive reference, but it appears that the signal handler and `sigwait` are mutually exclusive. If you handle the signal synchronously, using `sigwait`, the handler is never invoked.

For a discussion, see [About the ambiguous description of sigwait()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326290/about-the-ambiguous-description-of-sigwait)