# sigwait() repeatedly unblocked by SIGUSR1

Tags: c, process, operating-system, signals

I am writing a program that takes a list of UNIX commands from a file and executes them sequentially. To keep everything in order, I must have each command initialized and kept waiting for `SIGUSR1` via `sigwait()`. When every command is initialized, then every command can execute.

Usage: `> program.c input.txt`

However, it appears that SIGUSR1 is repeatedly called, completely surpassing `sigwait()`. What is going on here? I've tried so many different things, but it's recently modeled after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6326390/2612623). To rephrase, I want the signal to be raised for commands immediately after initialization. I want the signal to be unblocked when all commands are completely initialized

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void on_sigusr1(int sig)
{
// Note: Normally, it's not safe to call almost all library functions in a
// signal handler, since the signal may have been received in a middle of a
// call to that function.
    printf("SIGUSR1 received!\n");
}

int main(int arc, char* argv[])
{


    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(argv[1] ,"r");

    int BUF_SIZE = 100; 

    char *token;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    char programs[BUF_SIZE];
    char *commands[BUF_SIZE];

    int i = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file ) != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(programs, buffer);

        int length = strlen(buffer)-1;
        if (buffer[length] == '\n') 
        {
            buffer[length] = '\0';
        }

        i = 0;
        token = strtok(buffer," ");
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            commands[i++] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        commands[i] = 0;

        pid_t pids[counter];


        // Set a signal handler for SIGUSR1
        signal(SIGUSR1, &on_sigusr1);

    // At program startup, SIGUSR1 is neither blocked nor pending, so raising it
    // will call the signal handler
        raise(SIGUSR1);

    // Now let's block SIGUSR1
        sigset_t sigset;
        sigemptyset(&sigset);
        sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);

    // SIGUSR1 is now blocked, raising it will not call the signal handler
        printf("About to raise SIGUSR1\n");
        raise(SIGUSR1);
        printf("After raising SIGUSR1\n");


        for(i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
        {
            pids[i] = fork();

            if(pids[i] > 0)
            {
                printf("Child process %d ready to execute command %s", getpid(), programs);
                // SIGUSR1 is now blocked and pending -- this call to sigwait will return
                // immediately
                int sig;
                int result = sigwait(&sigset, &sig);
                if(result == 0) {
                    printf("Child process %d executing command %s", getpid(), programs);
                    execvp(commands[0], commands);   
                }
            }
        }

        // All programs have been launched
        for(i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
        {
            wait(&pids[i]);
        }

        // All programs are waiting to execute
        for (i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
        {
        // SIGUSR1 is now no longer pending (but still blocked).  Raise it again and
        // unblock it
            raise(SIGUSR1);
            printf("About to unblock SIGUSR1\n");
            sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
            printf("Unblocked SIGUSR1\n");
        }
    }

exit(0);
fclose(file);   
return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: Tried changing `signal()` to `sigaction()`. No change.

Comment: "*... SIGUSR1 is repeatedly called*" a signal isn't called. Please what exactly do you want to express?

Comment: Try using `sigaction` instead of `signal`.

Comment: @alk: I want the signal to be raised for commands immediately after initialization. I want the signal to be unblocked when all commands are completely initialized.

Comment: @mnunberg: Tried that, no change.

Comment: You should put code after `execvp()` to report an error and exit in case the `execvp()` returns (aka fails).  As it stands, if a command fails, it will go on to exit other commands.  Maybe your `on_sigusr1()` function should report the PID as well?  Reporting PID can often be helpful when trying to get multi-process systems working correctly.  Note that the `exit(0);` before the `fclose(file);` and `return 0;` makes the latter two statements irrelevant.  I'd remove the `exit(0);`.  Also, can you show the first few lines of the data file you're reading/executing commands from?

Comment: @MissRainbowdash: To me this looks as if in this big `while`-loop commands are read from file, exec'ed  and triggered one after the other.

Comment: And also: What is `counter` for?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider calling sigwait **after** checking to see if that pid is a child process.

So maybe put

int sig;

and

int result = sigwait(&sigset, &sig);

within an if statement that checks if the pid is == 0 which would indicate that it is a child. Otherwise you would be sigwaiting a parent process.

If the pid is greater than 0 it's a parent process id and if it's less than zero its an error.

Then for each process in your array of pids you would call kill(pid_array[i], SIGUSR1) to unblock it.

Comment: this example is a total mess.. Forking child that starts to executing parent's code, while parent is execvp childs code.. It should just crash on start.